# What is this little insect larvae on my cucumbers?

Tags: identification, vegetables, insects, cucumbers

Need help identifying these little <del>monsters</del> creatures on my cucumber plants. It doesn't look like a beetle but working along side beetles.

[image: Need help identifying these little monsters]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That is a [ladybug larvae](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coccinellidae) - don't kill it. It is eating pests, and is a beneficial insect. Are the beetles they were found with ladybugs? that would make sense. But [Mexican bean beetles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epilachna_varivestis) and [Cucumber beetles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cucumber_beetle) also look like ladybugs, I'll include a side by side comparison picture.

From left to right, ladybug, mexican bean beetle, and cucumber beetle:

[image][image]

From left to right, ladybug larva and mexican bean beetle larvae:

[image][image]

Cucumber beetle larva:

[image]

As you can see, the larvae are much easier to distinguish between than the adults are. I would leave the ladybug larvae on the plant, unless you want to spray it. In that case, carefully transport them to a new location, infested with aphids (one without ant farmers is preferable).